# What is the most efficient way to use rsync to confirm transfer of large folder

Tags: ssh, synchronization, backup, rsync

I’m using a synology ds214 and I have a 6tb folder I originally was using USB Copy to transfer to an external drive connected directly to the nas. That process failed somewhere along the way and I attempted to `rsync` each folder within the 6tb individually using the flags `-avPc`. What’s the most efficient  command to run to ensure that all the files are synced and completed?

Would `—-ignore-existing` be the best flag in this case?

Comment: What kind of failure? If you're using `-c` then rsync will have to read up to 6TB on both source and destination, so not very efficient. `--ignore-existing` and `-c` don't seem appropriate together (if you don't trust the existing data to be correct (`-c`) why would you ignore it (`--ignore-existing`) ?)

Comment: The failure with USB Copy was a storage issue but I increased the partition. I may have run `-c` with `--ignore-existing` while doing some of the individual folder transfers which I'm now realizing was not correct together. Should I start from scratch and reformat the destination and re run the rsync?

Comment: How upset will you be if you need the copy and it is corrupt? I used to store piles of USB disks containing multiple redundant copies of video masters in an fire safe; I had a schedule for spinning disks up to check they still worked and hadn't suffered bit-rot, and for migrating to newer disks. How much checking you do now really depends on how risk averse you are.

Comment: The folder is all photos and I'm using the copy to better organize them to eventually replace from the original source so I long way of saying it is very important to me that the destination data isn't corrupt.